# Promoting Skeptics.SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

After the public beta begins, we should promote this site to increase our number of experts and get some more traffic. A good starting point would be to promote the site to skeptical bloggers and on message boards targeted to skeptics.

Skeptic bloggers have already an audience that they could direct our way if they would blog about us. They might even join our community and answer some questions, if we're lucky. When we contact them, it would be good if we find people that already had some interaction with the blogger in question, as a request from someone they know carries more weight than if someone they never heard of asked them to promote some website they never heard of.

Posting on message boards about our site is also a good way to promote it. It also would be nice if established members of the boards in question would do that, if brand new users promote some website in their first post it looks somewhat like spamming. Even better would be to use an appropriate answer from this site to answer a question on the message board. This would [showcase our content](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/nominate-the-best-of-skeptics-se) and might lead some people our way. But don't just drop a link, the content here is CC-licensed, just copy the relevant part of an answer [with the correct attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), this will make a better impression.

These are just some ideas to promote our site, let's come up with some more.

Comment: Contribute content to showcase here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/442/nominate-the-best-of-skeptics-se

Answer (score 7):

### Bloggers:

- [PZ Myers on Pharyngula](http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/)
- [Orac on Respectful Insolence](http://scienceblogs.com/insolence/)
- [Phil Plait on Bad Astronomer](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/) (already gave us [coverage](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/03/10/skeptic-exchange/))
- [Ben Goldacre on Bad Science](http://www.badscience.net/)
- [Cory Doctorow on BoingBoing](http://craphound.com/)
- [Skepchick](http://skepchick.org/category/quickies/)

### Twitterers:

- [Simon Singh](http://www.simonsingh.net/)

### Message Boards:

- [James Randi Educational Foundation](http://forums.randi.org/forumindex.php)
- [The Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/index.php?) (not purely targeted at skeptics, but the right demographics)

### Podcasts:

- [The Skeptics’ Guide to the Universe](http://www.theskepticsguide.org/)

<sub>Please add more blogs and forums that you know, this post is community wiki and can be edited by anyone</sub>

Comment: [This](http://www.csicop.org/resources#skeptical_websites) looks like it may be useful for promotion.

Comment: Do you think popular youtube channels would fit this list? I.e. thunderf00t is constantly debunking creationism and is extremely popular. http://www.youtube.com/user/Thunderf00t?blend=1&ob=5 there are also a few channels dedicated to general "skepticism"

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget social media. A [large number of people](http://followerwonk.com/bio/?q=skeptic+|+sceptic&l=&n=&frmin=&frmax=&flmin=&flmax=) who self-describe [as skeptics](http://wefollow.com/twitter/skeptic) are active on Twitter and other similar sites (Facebook and so on). I'm one of them.

Although there was a fair amount of chatter about the old SkepticExchange experiment, I didn't see anyone announce that this version had gone into beta.  I only stumbled on this today because I happened to visit Area51 and decided to look.

UPDATE: I [blogged about the site on my Skeptical Software Tools](http://skeptools.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/gamification-skepticism-skeptic-questions-qa/) blog today. I thought it was worth some explanation of what exactly Stack Exchange brings to the table with this.  I plugged that on Twitter and I'll plug it once more tomorrow.

I also have some more Twitter updates scheduled to post later in the 90-day trial period.  Make sure to keep talking about the site, sometimes it takes several mentions before someone will get interested in it.  We need to get some buy-in by other top-tier skeptics on Twitter like Rebecca Watson, Phil Plait, Brian Dunning or others.  They have lots of followers.  Use those links in my first paragraph to find others to target too.

Comment: Phil just linked to our site!

Comment: I'll chime in with Tim.  There are many StackExchange functions to interface with social media.  I have experimented a little bit with one of my questions.  Will see what happens as a result.

Answer (score 2):

## Skeptic in the Pub Groups

They are active on Twitter and Facebook and can promote us to there members.

### United Kingdom

- [Bristol Skpetics](http://twitter.com/BristolSkeptics)
- [Bath Skeptics](http://twitter.com/BathSkeptics)
- [Westminster Skeptics](http://twitter.com/WestSkep)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to submit it to the [skeptics guide to the universe](http://www.theskepticsguide.org/) podcast they have a large audience and lot of connections in the skeptical world.